# What kind of monitoring system can we have for existing security systems in the vehicles?

Tags: monitoring, vehicle

The vehicles are fitted with a security system to track their movements and report it back to their owners if they are moved unauthorized.

My question is: can we have an additional security system or any third party system to monitor the existing security system? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

The security system on the vehicles would need some kind of an interface to allow access to the data from multiple sources.

Or, the third party system would have to be the approved recipient (customer?) of each of the vehicle's security system, and the third party would have to gather and report on all the data.

Short answer: API or hand-made aggregation.

Comment: Or the vehicle reports to an external entity (the security company) which reports back to the owner. In this scenario the user is the third-party by default.

Comment: Given the request was for third-party external security, your suggestion re-frames the question, else it is no different than an API.